Failing to authenticate with AWS while running spark-sql on EKS
I am using kubernetes as cluster manager & scheduler to run my spark workloads. While I am able to run spark-submit along with IAM access support; I am not able run spark-sql.
Here's the command I am using to submit the jobs -
spark-submit
spark-submit \
  --master k8s://<k8s-master-url> \
  --name spark-pi \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/spark:3.3.1 \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=s3a://<bucket-name>/ \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=prod-spark-sa \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider \
  --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.eventLog.dir=s3a://<bucket-name>/logs/ \
  --conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=s3a://<bucket-name>/logs/ \
s3a://<bucket-name>/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.0.jar

It runs successfully and give the output; It is able to fetch the jar artifacts from the bucket and using the same service account I am passing here.
but when I am trying to run spark-sql using below command -
spark-sql \
--master k8s://<k8s-master-url> \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/spark:3.3.1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
--packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4 \
--conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog \
--conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris=thrift://172.xx.xx.xx:10000 \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=s3a://<bucket-name>/warehouse/ \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=prod-spark-sa \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName=prod-spark-sa

I am getting below error -
24/05/14 12:47:38 WARN DeltaLog: Failed to parse s3://<bucket-name>/587f8193-b09a-41a5-9d1d-a14f84911567/tables/e59dc872-36d5-4409-8ee9-dfcbd6f3d63d/_delta_log/_last_checkpoint. This may happen if there was an error during read operation, or a file appears to be partial. Sleeping and trying again.
java.lang.NullPointerException: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName
        at com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider$Builder.<init>(STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.java:390)
        at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.internal.STSProfileCredentialsService.getAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider(STSProfileCredentialsService.java:31)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.securitytoken.STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.getProfileCredentialsProvider(STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider.java:39)


I have an idea why this is not working ..
Can you please share the IRSA configuration, mainly the policies part ? attached to the role.

are you able to access the S3 if you use the K8s Service account in question with a Pod? I am assuming that role annotation is working properly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html
and you are able to see the SA details with kubectl as well:
kubectl describe serviceaccount <service-account> -n spark


@Ravish yes my service account is working perfectly fine and is able to access s3. I have tested it using spark-submit as well as manually from inside of the pod.

@SaifeddineRajhi I've s3fullaccess attached to role & trust policy as -
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::123:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.region.amazonaws.com/id/DDDXYZ1234351"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "oidc.eks.region.amazonaws.com/id/DDDXYZ1234351:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
                "oidc.eks.region.amazonaws.com/id/DDDXYZ1234351:sub": "system:serviceaccount:spark:prod-dp-spark-sa"

lmk if you need more details

your spark-sql pods running in EKS are missing the required IAM role

create a new IAM role with necessary permissions that your Pod needs (IAM actions) to access the s3 bucket and other required aws services
create a new service account in your EKS cluster
associate created IAM role with a Kubernetes service account
configure your pod to use that Kubernetes service account spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName: my-service-account

Refer:
For 1 to 3 steps: Configure a Kubernetes service account to assume an IAM role
For 4: Configure Pods to use a Kubernetes service account
PS: make sure that your role has sts:AssumeRole permissions to let it be assumed by the pod
——
Alternatively, you can also use EKS Pod Identity Agent addon to achieve this, refer this page: Set up the Amazon EKS Pod Identity Agent

I've done exactly the same!

can you kubectl exec that pod and check if you can run
aws sts get-caller-identity
and
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name>
works?
